# nohup has no effect when running a process background with ampersand in the end?

Tags: linux, nohup

As far as I know, `nohup` can keep process running without caring about terminal's exit. But I found that when I run a process in background (without `nohup`) using ampersand(`&`) in the end, then exit from the terminal, I can still find the process running in the machine.

Here is an simple example; I run the below command and then exit the terminal:

```
ping localhost &
```

But, I found the "ping" process still running in the machine, even though I did not use `nohup` here.  Am I misunderstanding `nohup`'s real usage?

Comment: Find the `pid` of the process with `pidof ping`, then `kill pid`. (or just type `top` find the pid in the tree and type `k` for `kill` and enter the `pid`.) Yes, `ping` will run forever, unless you limit the `-c (count)` . If you only have that `ping` process running, just `killall ping` will do. (you can also type `fg` in the same terminal you launched `ping` in to bring it back to the foreground, then just do `[ctrl + c]`. (lots of ways to skin this cat)

Comment: `nohup command &` and `command &` is not the same.    the last can be bring to front by running `fg`, also you can lookup it by `jobs`

Comment: Not only the ping process, I found any process that can run for a long time, when I put it background without using nohup and exit from the terminal, it wont be affected by the terminal. So I doubt  whether it needs nohup here, why is nohup always used along with ampersand(&), and what is the best scenario to use nohup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the reason you are seeing your process still running after logging off from your session is that probably your shell doesn't send a sighup at logoff. 
You can confirm that by running:

```
shopt | grep hupon
```

I assume it will return something like `huponexit off`...

It's not guaranteed for every Linux/shell to do that, so in order to stay safe and have your script portable, I suggest using `nohup`. E.g.

```
nohup ping localhost &
```

To confirm you can also enable `huponexit`, by running

```
shopt -s huponexit
```

Then run your command without `nohup`, logoff/exit the shell and check if your process is still running.